# Custom preprocessing using piplines

Tags: machine-learning, python, preprocessing, pipelines

I have searched a lot for this issue but unfortunately came up with nothing.
Usually in a ML model, during preprocessing, we use `Pipelines` and `ColumnTransformer` to group together preprocessing steps and the algorithm. Now the problem with `Pipelines` is that it performs the specified preprocessing for all the columns. For example if I specify:-

```
pipeline = Pipeline(steps = [('scale', StandardScaler()), ('encode', OneHotEncoder())])
```

The above pipeline will apply Standard scaler to all the columns of the dataset and the encoder will apply to all categorical column. I don't want that. I want different preprocessing techniques for different columns. For example out of 5 numerical columns, I want Standard scaling only for 3 columns and for the rest 2 I want Robust scaling. Similarly for out of 4 categorical columns, I want `OneHotEncoder` for 2 columns and `LabelEncoder` for 2 columns.

How can I implement this using `Pipelines` or `make_pipelines`? Or can it even be implemented?

**Edit based on comment**:

I tried the `ColumnTransofrmer` method but it gives me an error on fitting:

```
data = pd.read_csv('cars_sampled.csv')
data

data1 = data.copy(deep = True)
data1

y = np.log(data2['price'])
data2.drop(['price'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

num1 = ['powerPS']
num2 = ['kilometer', 'age']
cat_impute1 = ['fuelType', 'gearbox', 'model']
cat_impute2 = ['vehicleType', 'notRepairedDamage']
cat_encode1 = ['model', 'fuelType', 'gearbox', 'notRepairedDamage', 'vehicleType', 'brand']


preproc = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [                                            
                                            ('num1', StandardScaler(), num1), 
                                            ('num2', RobustScaler(), num2),
                                            
                            ('cat_impute1', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent'), cat_impute1), 
                            ('cat_impute2', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'constant', fill_value = 'Missing'), cat_impute2),

                                            
                                            ('cat_encode1', OneHotEncoder(), cat_encode1) 
                                            ])

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("preprocessor", preproc),
        ("model", LinearRegression())
    ]
)

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(data2, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 69)

pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

The error is in the last line `pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)` and it is as follows:

```
ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.
```

**Edit 2**:

```
data = pd.read_csv('cars_sampled.csv')
data

data1 = data.copy(deep = True)
data1

y = np.log(data2['price'])
data2.drop(['price'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

num1 = ['powerPS']
num2 = ['kilometer', 'age']
cat_impute1 = ['fuelType', 'gearbox', 'model']
cat_impute2 = ['vehicleType', 'notRepairedDamage']
cat_encode1 = ['model', 'fuelType', 'gearbox', 'notRepairedDamage', 'vehicleType', 'brand']

cat_pipe = Pipeline(steps = [('impute', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')),
                ('encode', OneHotEncoder())])


preproc = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [                                            
                                            ('num1', StandardScaler(), num1), 
                                            ('num2', RobustScaler(), num2),
                                            ('cat', cat_pipe, cat_encode1) 
                                            ])

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("preprocessor", preproc),
        ("model", LinearRegression())
    ]
)

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(data2, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 69)

pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the `ColumnTransformer`, which you should be able to use to achieve this (see also [this page from the scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html):

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, RobustScaler, OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("num1", StandardScaler(), ["col1", "col2", "col3"]),
        ("num2", RobustScaler(), ["col4", "col5"]),
        ("cat1", OneHotEncoder(), ["col6", "col7"]),
        ("cat2", LabelEncoder(), ["col8", "col9"]),
    ]
)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
        ("classifier", LogisticRegression())
    ]
)
```

Comment: The page from scikit learn does not have any code like the one you mention in your answer where we can apply different preprocessing steps for different columns by mentioning them as a list in `ColumnTransformer`.

Comment: It does, see the second code block in the provided link. They have specified two types of preprocessing steps for either numerical or categorial features. The specific columns to apply the transformers to are specified by the variables `numeric_features` and `categorical_features`, which are both lists.

Comment: Unfortunately the above method does not work. See my updated question.

Comment: That error is not caused by the way you are using the `ColumnTransformer`, but by the fact that you are using the `LabelEncoder` on feature columns instead of the target labels. [The documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) explicitly says 'This transformer should be used to encode target values, i.e. y, and not the input X.'. See also [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py#L102), where the `fit_transform` method only takes two arguments (`self` and `y`).

Comment: Ok now I'm getting a different error. Seep my updated question. This is weird as I am encoding the categorical columns.

Comment: This seems to be caused by the fact that the pipeline is trying to convert the data array to a sparse array, for which all values need to be numbers. This is however not possible as you still have some values which are strings (i.e. the categorical columns) since you are applying the imputing and encoding steps in parallel (as separate transforms in the `ColumnTransformer`) instead of sequentially.

Comment: As I am understanding, `ColumnTransformer` applies all the transforms sequentially. So in sequential order, `num1` and `num2` will be scaled, then `cat_impute1` and `cat_impute2` will be imputed (again sequentially) and finally `cat_encode1` will be encoded. How am I then applying imputing and encoding in parallel? Can you copy my code edit it and post it in your answer?

Comment: `ColumnTransformer` does not apply the steps in a sequantial order but in parallel. This can specifically be seen in the [`_fit_transform` method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py#L592) where the [`Parallel` class from `joblib`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html#joblib.Parallel) is used to apply all transformers.

Comment: How do I apply the steps sequentially then?

Comment: You can define a separate pipeline for the categorical features (to perform the imputing and encoding sequentially), which you can then use as a transformer in the `ColumnTransformer`. See [this code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zluvsand/2cd99263f6d23f24b733badbdf306100/raw/9f7973897243abf7fced4087b42fe18eb72e2ca2/columntransformer_categorical_transformers_only.py) for example where a pipeline is used within a `ColumnTransformer`.

Comment: I am afraid I didn't make myself clear. I want to perform preprocessing for each column differently i.e. perform different preprocessing steps on each columns. I can't do that in a `Pipeline`. The example you gave performs imputing with 'missing' and OHE for all cat columns which is exactly the opposite of what I'm looking to do. I want to perform OHE for some of the columns, Target encoding for some and so on. (Encoding is just an example. This applies to both cat and num columns and all and any preprocessing techniques.)

Comment: I can do different preprocessing for individual columns in a `ColumnTransformer` but then I'm facing the error as described in my question

Comment: You can do that, but like I said, to apply the different steps sequentially for the categorical columns you have to use another pipeline *within* the `ColumnTransformer`. For example, you can replace the `OneHotEncoder` by a `Pipeline` which contains both an imputing and encoding step.

Comment: You mean like this? Check Edit 2